# How To Deploy a C++ DLL

Tags: c++, dll, installation

I have written a dll in visual studio community 2017. To be used as a general purpose library. Which could be ideally used for any c++ program for any compiler.
How will I best deploy it. (An installer)

In Visual Studio, I can simply add the project and reference it through settings in my IDE, but for it to work in any IDE, what kind of installer project should i use and what all files should be included and how.

Comment: If you want your library to be used in as many platforms/systems/compilers as possible, make it open source and use CMake as build system.

Comment: Why a dll? Could you turn it into a static library instead?

Comment: Still even if it is a static library how would you deploy it

Comment: As a *static* library, the code becomes part of the executable.  No need to deploy a static library.

Comment: I am not deploying an executable rather a library that can be used for multiple executables

Comment: *"multiple executables"* - well, only those compiled with same compiler and version! With different versions, you are likely doomed to run into implementation incompatibilities...

Comment: So I'm better of not deploying an independent DLL? And only release it with an executable?

Answer (score 2):

You can't deploy a C++ DLL for all compilers. C++ doesn't have an ABI. Not even MSVC++ is compatible across versions, let alone compilers from different vendors.

The Windows solution for binary compatibility is COM. Conveniently, MSVC++ will use the COM ABI for classes that inherit from `IUnknown`, although you'll also have to adhere to other COM rules for full compatibility. E.g. you can't rely on `dynamic_cast`, you need `QueryInterface`.

Comment: Had to work with COM quite some while ago. Ugly API... If conversions are not too complex, I personally would prefer creating a C-compatible library interface (`extern "C"` for exported functions) instead. Makes porting to other systems more easy as well.